# Finding multiple Punctuation marks occurring in a series in a given string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have below strings -

```
var string1 = "When did Harry meet Sally ???";
var string2 = "When did Harry meet Sally ?$@";
var string3 = "When did Harry meet Sally ?";
```

I need to report string3 as correct string out of the above options. With

```
string1.match(/[:!?+\<">'$‘;@€`*&.\\/]{2}/g)
```

I am able to say string1 is incorrect. How can detect that string2 is incorrect ?

Comment: What about "What a beautiful day!!!"

Comment: so a valid string should contain less than 3 consecutive puctuations?

Comment: valid string should contain only one punctuation. It is fine if there are multiple punctuation but they should not be in series together.

Comment: "What a beautiful day!!!"  should show as incorrect "What a beautiful day!" should be the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead to check if current character is a symbol and character following it is also symbol then return false.

#### Edit1

To handle cases like `? @`, you can remove all spaces and then test it. This will not modify original string, and is only used for validation purpose.

**Sample**

```js
function validateString(str){
  return !/[^a-z0-9](?=[^a-z0-9])/gi.test(str.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
}


var string1 = "When did Harry meet Sally ???";
var string2 = "When did Harry meet Sally ?$@";
var string3 = "When did Harry meet Sally ?";
var string4 = "When did Harry meet Sally ? @";
var string5 = "When did Harry meet Sally ? test";

[string1, string2, string3, string4, string5].forEach(function(s){
  console.log(validateString(s))
})
```

Comment: What if we have to show  `var string4 = "When did Harry meet Sally ? @" `;  as incorrect ?

Answer (score 1):

Push these sting to an array , so that i , they can can be looped, The regex will return the last two characters.

```
var string1 = "When did Harry meet Sally ???";
var string2 = "When did Harry meet Sally ?$@";
var string3 = "When did Harry meet Sally ?";

var stringArray = [string1,string2,string3]

stringArray.forEach(function(item){
// will get last two characters else null
 var x = item.match(/[:!?+\<">'$‘;@€`*&.\\/]{2}/g);
 // if null then log the string
 x=== null?console.log(item):''
})
```